# Removing n characters from the beginning / end of a record with regex

Tags: sql, regex

If I have a column, say:

```
paths
```

And paths holds the absolute path to a file.

If I wanted, to remove n characters from the beginning and end of the records, for the entire path column - would this be possible?

Edit - example:

Lets say there are records in paths like so:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-1.txt
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-2.txt
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-3.txt
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-4.txt
```

I would like to update the records to be:

```
Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-1
Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-2
Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-3
Users\Alex\Documents\Files\File-4
```

So essentially removing n characters from the beginning and end of an entire column.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: **Yes** it's possible show us your attempt and where you are stuck...

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: For every record...?

Comment: Yes, I'd rather not do it one by one for all of the records.

Comment: @alexkirb Try my query now.

Comment: @alexkirb if using `postgresql` update your question. Do NOT tag other tags when this isn't what you are using..

Answer (score 0):

A general regex solution would be:

```
^(?:.{3})(.*)(?:.{4})$
# that is match exactly three chars in the beginning (non-capturing group)
# match everything up to the end of the string
# but as .* is sweet-tempered...
# it gives back the four characters in the end ($)
# your match is in the first group
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pO6yT5/1)

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern and replace with nothing

```
^.{3}|.{4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/333)

Comment: Just curious: Are you really always using the ***same*** regex101 link (with different versions, that is)?

Comment: @jan, are you really checking all my answers to see that it is!!

Comment: @alphabravo: No, I was not, but there was the version dropdown stating "Version 333" - so I made a guided assumption :-)

Answer (score -1):

As you tagged `SQL` which implies Standard SQL:

> Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ANSI SQL.

There's no need for anything more complicated than a SUBSTRING, you just need to calculate the number of characters you want to strip:

```
SUBSTRING(path FROM 4 FOR CHARACTER_LENGTH(path)-7)
```

This is also working as-is in PostgreSQL :)

Comment: What do you mean by *strips out character*? Yes, it strips off the first 3 and the last 4 characters and this is exactly what the OP asked for. If you don't believe me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8d41/1